# Looking for an Advanced Limits Textbook

Tags: limits, infinity

I'm Looking for an advanced textbook on limits .
There is an alternative way to finding limits which I couldnt find anywhere on the internet or in any of my Books about Calculus that specificly teaches that and prooves the formulas.

Simple Example : Sin(x) acts like y = x near zero and thats proved by linear approximation Or simply by looking at the graph.

A more compliacted Example which I'm looking for a proof:

when $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{ax^n+bx^{n-1}+...} $$
is equvalent to :

$$\sqrt{n} {.}|{x+\frac{b}{na}}| $$

and there are a lot of formulas like this which I like to learn very carefully and efficient.

We call this things equivalence relations of limits in our country and we show it with "~"

Another one :

when $$\lim_{x\to \infty} {1^k + 2^k + 3^k + 4^k + ... + n^k}  $$

is equivalent to :

$$ \frac{1}{k+1} {.} {n^{k+1}} $$

I'd appreciate It if someone could help me find a good resource to this approach of limit finding which is really fast sometimes.

Comment: Any standard *real analysis* texts should do I think.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=cbbCAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=kolmogorov+fomin+introductory+real+analysis&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwix_N-gycXPAhXJ7IMKHR4zBG4Q6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=kolmogorov%20fomin%20introductory%20real%20analysis&f=false

Comment: Couldn't find what I was looking for. Which chapter should I Check out? @StubbornAtom

Comment: There are several texts on analysis having a separate chapter on limits. You could search this site also for that.

Comment: I could'nt find these formulas in there.